# Video streaming

Tags: open-source, video, streaming, tagging

anyone that can help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to setup a video streaming service from my server. I want to store videos on this. Now I was thinking of streaming the video through some form of player (e.g. JWPlayer) and (a) allowing users to step through the video frame by frame (b) tagging the video by associating text (data) with any frame (time) in the video (c) being able to jump to these tags (d) use the tags to reference the video.

What are the best components for achieving this with say up to 100 concurrent users?

Max.

Comment: Is the server you are streaming from Windows or Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the server architecture you'd use for this, but definitely look into:
http://flowplayer.org/index.html as a supplement

Comment: JW player is also an option. And is free.