# What do i need to add video streaming capabilities to drupal 7

Tags: drupal, video-streaming, drupal-modules

i need to add video streaming capabilities to drupal. I need this functions:

- Some users must be able to create
  content with video inside it. It must
  be easy, the best idea would be
  adding a new content type (rich
  media) and then the user can choose
  to either upload a video from his pc
  or choose a video that has been
  already uploaded
- Registered user must
  have the possibility to upload videos
  that are viewed by a moderator before
  publishing them

All video must stay on my server  (privacy reasons and so on), what i'm asking is: is there any drupal modules that any of you has used that does such things?

for streaming video from my server do i need some special "video streaming server"?
i'v checked flowplayer as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898030/video-streaming) question, but i don't get if i need to setup some extras on the server or not.

EDIT - in case, has anyone tried to use [Kaltura](http://drupal.org/project/kaltura)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a WebTV Module on top of [NaviCast](http://www.navicast.net/) Streaming API. I used flowplayer for playback. I also setup adStreamer plugin with flowplayer.

NaviCast is a paid service and gives you a desktop application to manage your videos.

Answer (score 1):

In the end i used the [video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module with the [flowplayer](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer) module. Simple and very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend MediaFront. It is pretty much stand-alone (needs HTML5), and has a tutorial video. It is the only streaming solution that worked for me.